# Is there a readable (less formal) version of Ethereum Yellow Paper?

Tags: yellow-paper

The "Yellow Paper" is Ethereum's formal specification.

https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper

The problem is that it's difficult to read for people not familiar with formal specifications.

**[Q]**: is there a readable (less formal) version of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since few days there is "Beige Paper", which is a rewrite of the Yellowpaper in non-Yellowpaper syntax, which is readable by a broader audience.

- GitHub Project: https://github.com/chronaeon/beigepaper/
- Shortcut to the PDF: https://github.com/chronaeon/beigepaper/blob/master/beigepaper.pdf (Beta-Release)