# Solidity: Info on How it works on the low level

Tags: solidity, evm

I'm looking for information on how Solidity works on the low level and how exactly it gets executed or run on the EVM?

Do you have any documentation or Papers that describe that?
Thank you!

Comment: Solidity is not directly executed. It is compiled to EVM bytecode. Only the bytecode is executed. The bytecode runs on the Ethereum Virtual Machine which is specified in the yellow paper https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

Answer (score 4):

As Briomkez already wrote, Solidity is not directly executed. It is compiled to EVM bytecode. This is specified in the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

There is also a more readable version of it - BeigePaper (see "[Is there a readable (less formal) version of Ethereum Yellow Paper?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41375/is-there-a-readable-less-formal-version-of-ethereum-yellow-paper)")

For viewing the bytecode and stepping through it, you can use the [Remix Web IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org).

Finally, there is also [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/). For advanced topics, you can look at [Soidity in Depth](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/solidity-in-depth.html).

Answer (score 2):

A whole chapter about EVM in this great book:

https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/13evm.asciidoc

Im pretty sure that if you need anything else might be there